# Rails/Webrick - customize the Bad Request webrick page (hide version)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webrick

I have a webserver (behind an nginx), when I send a bad request to the Rail application (ex: to an URL that does not exist in the app - error 404), I get an error message from webrick, like this :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 07 Mar 2016 05:25:02 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 323
Connection: keep-alive

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY>
<H1>Bad Request</H1>
bad URI `/admin/
boot.ini'.
<HR>
<ADDRESS>
WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.2.0/2014-12-25) at
192-168-5-51.compute.internal:3000
</ADDRESS>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Now as you can see this message contains the web server name (WEBrick) the version, as well as the Ruby version.

My question is how can I remove this message (send back empty body)
OR customize the page and remove the `<ADDRESS>` element ?